# Как убрать регулярным выражением слеш из ссылки, если он есть?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть перечень ссылок, некоторые из них заканчиваются на `/`.

Как их убрать?

Нужно убрать только `/` (слеш если он есть), который стоит после файла:

```
 https://somesite.com//gallery/2020/6/4/19n.jpg
 https://somesite.com//gallery/14tn.jpg/   - здесь убрать
 https://somesite.com//gallery/2020/6/4/14tn.jpg/   - здесь убрать
 https://somesite.com//gallery/
```

Comment: Зачем вам тут регулярные выражения? На каком языке программирования вы пишете?

Comment: `(?<=jpg)\/(?=\s)`

Comment: @КириллМалышев а при чем здесь язык программирования?

Comment: @teran, скорее всего, это можно сделать без регулярок стандартными средствами работы со ссылками и строками.

Comment: @КириллМалышев я о том, что с чего вы вообще взяли, что автор что-то программирует. Поскольку в вопросе речи вообще не идет о программировании, то надо полагать, что у него просто имеется текстовый файл со ссылками, в котором надо провести замену.

Comment: @teran, а я не стал полагать и спросил.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Регулярное выражение: `(?<=jpg)\/(?=\s)`

Пример на JavaScript:

```js
const regex = /(?<=jpg)\/(?=\s)/gm;

const str = ` https://somesite.com//gallery/2020/6/4/19n.jpg
https://somesite.com//gallery/14tn.jpg/   - здесь убрать
https://somesite.com//gallery/2020/6/4/14tn.jpg/   - здесь убрать
https://somesite.com//gallery/2020/6/4/14tn.jpg/
https://somesite.com//gallery/ `;

console.log(str.replace(regex, ''));
```

Подробнее:
`(?<=jpg)` - группа позитивного просмотра назад, проверяем что перед слеш есть текст jpg
`\/` - экранируем слеш, т.к. чаще всего они используется в роли разделителя. В нашем случае он нужен как обычный стринг
`(?=\s)` - группа позитивного просмотра вперед, проверяем что после символа слеш идет любой пробельный, `\s` эквивалентно `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`

Answer (score 2):

в каком-нибудь notepad++ делаем замену `\.(jpe?g|png|gif)/$` на `.$1`
нужные расширения файлов перечисляем через `|` внутри скобок

Answer (score 1):

Сохранить список ссылок в файл urls.txt:

```
https://somesite.com//gallery/2020/6/4/19n.jpg
https://somesite.com//gallery/14tn.jpg/
https://somesite.com//gallery/2020/6/4/14tn.jpg/
https://somesite.com//gallery/
```

В терминале выполнить команду:

```
cat urls.txt | sed 's/\.jpg\/$/.jpg/'
```

Результат:

```
https://somesite.com//gallery/2020/6/4/19n.jpg
https://somesite.com//gallery/14tn.jpg
https://somesite.com//gallery/2020/6/4/14tn.jpg
https://somesite.com//gallery/
```